# Delete emails using bash shell?

Tags: bash, shell

I have a bunch of useless emails that I want to get rid. They are in the GB range, so Horde mail is freaking out when manually loading inbox. Thus, I'm trying to do this via the following shell script:

```
#!/bin/bash    
find /home/abc/mail/new/ -type f -print | xargs rm
find /home/xyz/mail/new/ -type f -print | xargs rm
find /home/qwe/mail/new/ -type f -print | xargs rm
```

Individually, `find /home/abc/mail/new/ -type f -print | xargs rm` works just fine. However, running them in the bash script doesn't seem to do anything. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: `find ... -exec rm -- {} +` is going to be considerably less buggy than `-print | xargs rm`. If you want to use xargs without bugs, it needs to be `-print0 | xargs -0 rm -- `

Comment: Need to use `xargs` due to "Argument list too long" problem.

Comment: Not that I'm certain that that has anything to do with your problem. Run `exec 2>/path/to/logfile` to log stderr at the top of your script, and follow it with `set -x`.

Comment: `-exec ... {} +` also solves the "argument list too long" problem, and it's not -- as aforementioned -- full of bugs.

Comment: Try passing xargs a filename with a space in it, or a filename that contains quotes. (When I refer to "bugs", I'm referring to specification failures, not implementation ones; an xargs that implements the POSIX standard for its behavior will treat whitespace as a division between input names, and quotes as syntactic rather than literal).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Is my syntax of the bash script fine? I can put the commands on separate lines and it won't screw up? I will try what you suggest.

Comment: The syntax is fine, though there's no reason for it to be separate commands -- you could run `find /home/{abc,xyz,qwe}/mail/new -type f -exec rm -- {} +` as a single command searching all those directories.

Comment: BTW, any chance this might be saved as a DOS-format text file (with CRLF line-endings, vs Unix LF-only newlines)? That would explain why it's not running -- it would be trying to invoke `$'rm\r'`, not `rm`.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Do you mean `/home/{abc,xyz,qwe}/m‌​ail/new`?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I used your suggestion `find ... -exec rm -- {} +` and it worked! THanks!